# Car Rental at Milan Airport

Tags: car-rentals, italy, mxp, lin

I am planning to fly to Milan, rent a car, drive up to the Italian Lakes, and return the car the same day; around the first week of November.

I tried to check online at the [airport's website](http://www.milanomalpensa-airport.com/en), but I didn't see any car rental companies listed.

Is there an on-site car rental at the airport? I would like to pick up and drop off the car at the airport rather than try to negotiate the public transport during the return (which will be at night).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a link in the bottom of every page:

[image]

Comment: Can't believe I missed this :-/

Answer (score 4):

Try searching for your "favorite car company milan locations".

The first two I tried Hertz and Europcar showed locations at both Linate and Malpensa Airports.  I imagine all the majors will also have desks there.

Answer (score 4):

There is plenty of car rental agencies in MXP. I would recommend to book in advance, an easy way to so is from [rentalcars.com](http://www.rentalcars.com) which I tested several times and is reliable. From there you can see the list of providers available and you may choose to browse on each provider's website if you prefer to deal with it without a third party.

It may not be your case but bear in mind that it is compulsory to have winter tires or snow chains aboard in certain areas of Italy from the 15th of November. This is mandatory regardless of the fact that there is actually snow or ice on the street.

Comment: +1 but just to make sure, do you have any affiliation with the mentioned website?

Comment: nope, I just tried in Milan, both LIN and MXP and it worked, I will edit the answer to make sure people don't feel that way though.

Comment: Do you know what areas?

Comment: Don't use "rental cars" or any other third-party web site.  If (for some reason) you must use a third party web site, just use expedia.  But it's always better to simply use the direct web site of the major car companies.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid many areas, including Como and, in general, where chances of snow are real. But this rule takes effect from the 15th of November (in some areas might be later) until late March/April.